# Adding FancyBox into Google GeoChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, fancybox, onclicklistener

To begin, I am extremely new to coding, and most of what I've done has been collecting pieces and altering snippets to suit my needs as I try to tie everything together.

More to the point, I have created a Google GeoChart which I have pasted into this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tehgugs/APTYA/3/

My goal is to have a mouseover tooltip, and an onclick action where a text box appears with additional data. What I am looking for in function is practically identical to http://apirio.boostlabs.com/demo/1/state.php?year=2009

However, I do not know how to finish up the code similar to what boost labs used. 
I initiated the new variable for use in onClick

```
  var countrydata = [];
  countrydata['Colombia'] = "Text, more text <br> tons of text";
  countrydata['Turkey'] = "This should be additional text";
```

and at the end followed what Boostlabs did and am beginning to call the variable

```
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart-canvas'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

google.visualization.events.addListener(
  'chart-canvas', 'regionClick',
  function(e) {
    var duration = countrydata[e['region']];
```

Boost Labs follows with

```
 $('#printHere').html(duration);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
```

but I am not sure what that code's purpose is.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you!